# How do I make a slider input depend on a reactive variable and change depending on the columns?

Tags: shiny

> `I have a larger database, but this example simplifies what I want to achieve:
>
> Problem: I want the update of the SLIDER INPUT to depend on the "selectVar" and therefore the minimum and maximum values ​​of the sliderIput are updated. When I do it individually, that is:`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

#---- Parametros de Entrada ----

Dregistros <- data.frame("comunidades"=c ("Pocona", "Cercado","Punata"),
                          "Sexo_Total"= c(23,26,7),
                         "Sexo_H"= c(43,16,17),
                         "Sexo_M"= c(113,286,177))
#----- Entorno de SHINY APP ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Población Cuenca"),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 230,
                   #------Seleccion de Variables----- 
                   selectInput("variable","Seleccione la variable",choices = c("Total"="Sexo_Total",
                                                                               "Total Hombres"="Sexo_H",
                                                                               "Total Mujeres"="Sexo_M")),
                   uiOutput("right_screen")),

  dashboardBody(DTOutput("tabla")))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   #----- SELECCION DE VARIABLES DEL CENSO---- 
  selectedVar <- reactive({switch(input$variable,
                                  "Sexo_Total"=Dregistros$Sexo_Total,
                                  "Sexo_H"=Dregistros$Sexo_H,
                                  "Sexo_M"=Dregistros$Sexo_M) })
  #---- SLIDER INPUT -----  
  output$right_screen<- renderUI({
    #input$updateSlider
    sliderInput("mInput",label = "slider input",min(Dregistros$selectedVar()),
                                                max(Dregistros$selectedVar()),
                                                value =range(Dregistros$selectedVar()))
  })
  #-----FILTRO CON VARIABLES ----
  filteredData <- reactive({Dregistros %>%
      filter(Dregistros$selectedVar() >= input$mInput[1] & Dregistros$selectedVar() <= input$mInput[2])
  }) 
  #---- TABLA----  
  output$tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(filteredData(),options = list(scrollX = TRUE))})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
 #---- SLIDER INPUT -----  
  output$right_screen<- renderUI({
    #input$updateSlider
    sliderInput("mInput",label = "slider input",min(Dregistros$Sexto_Total),
                                                max(Dregistros$Sexto_Total),
                                                value =range(Dregistros$Sexto_Total))
  })
  #-----FILTRO CON VARIABLES ----
  filteredData <- reactive({Dregistros %>%
      filter(Dregistros$Sexto_Total >= input$mInput[1] & Dregistros$Sexto_Total <= input$mInput[2])
```

`IT WORKS WELL, but when I want to make it depend on a selection, the minimum and maximum values ​​do not appear, I am doing something wrong and any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you so much`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectedVar already contains the dataframe column:

```
selectedVar <- reactive({switch(input$variable,
                                  "Sexo_Total"=Dregistros$Sexo_Total,
                                  "Sexo_H"=Dregistros$Sexo_H,
                                  "Sexo_M"=Dregistros$Sexo_M) })
```

So while updating the slider min/max, you don't need to subset from `Dregistros` again. You can simply do:

```
sliderInput("mInput",label = "slider input",min(selectedVar()),
                                                max(selectedVar()),
                                                value =range(selectedVar()))
```

And similarly in your filter part:

```
filteredData <- reactive({Dregistros %>%
      filter(selectedVar() >= input$mInput[1] & selectedVar() <= input$mInput[2])
  })
```

[image]

#### **EDIT: For the plot**

ggplot takes variable names not vectors. Your `selectedVar` returns a vector, not the name of the variable. Moreover, ggplot2 takes the variable names in unquoted manner (`aes(x = Petal.Length)` not `aes(x = "Petal.Length")`). When passing strings, the recommended method is to use `.data[[variable_holding_column_name]]`. So modify your plot code to:

```r
output$plot <- renderPlot({
        req(filteredData())
        ggplot(filteredData(),
               aes(x = comunidades,
                   y = .data[[input$variable]],
                   col = .data[[input$variable]])) + 
        geom_point()
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, excellent works very well. Just one thing, when I add a simple dot plot. It updates the entire slider based on the parameter and also the graph, but when moving the slider the table works but NOT the graph, an unknown error appears.

Comment: #---- PLOT----  
  `output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(filteredData(), aes(x=comunidades, y=selectedVar(), col=selectedVar()))+ geom_point()
      })`

Comment: Added edit for the plot. Essentially you have to pass the name of a variable to ggplot not the actual vector itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

#---- Parametros de Entrada ----

Dregistros <- data.frame("comunidades"=c ("Pocona", "Cercado","Punata"),
                          "Sexo_Total"= c(23,26,7),
                         "Sexo_H"= c(43,16,17),
                         "Sexo_M"= c(113,286,177))
#----- Entorno de SHINY APP ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Población Cuenca"),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 230,
                   #------Seleccion de Variables----- 
                   selectInput("variable","Seleccione la variable",choices = c("Total"="Sexo_Total",
                                                                               "Total Hombres"="Sexo_H",
                                                                               "Total Mujeres"="Sexo_M")),
                   uiOutput("right_screen")),

  dashboardBody(DTOutput("tabla"),
                plotOutput("plot"))
  
  
  )
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   #----- SELECCION DE VARIABLES DEL CENSO---- 
  selectedVar <- reactive({switch(input$variable,
                                  "Sexo_Total"=Dregistros$Sexo_Total,
                                  "Sexo_H"=Dregistros$Sexo_H,
                                  "Sexo_M"=Dregistros$Sexo_M) })
  #---- SLIDER INPUT -----  
  output$right_screen<- renderUI({
    #input$updateSlider
    sliderInput("mInput",label = "slider input",min(selectedVar()),
                max(selectedVar()),
                value =range(selectedVar()))
    
  })
  #-----FILTRO CON VARIABLES ----
  filteredData <- reactive({Dregistros %>%
      filter(selectedVar() >= input$mInput[1] & selectedVar() <= input$mInput[2])
  })
  #---- TABLA----  
  output$tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(filteredData(),options = list(scrollX = TRUE))})
  
  #---- PLOT----  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(filteredData(), aes(x=comunidades, y=selectedVar(), col=selectedVar()))+ geom_point()


  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```